# Best way to register a checkBox toggle in a listView

Tags: android, listview, checkbox

So my question is about registering checkBox clicks in a listView. Ideally I want something along the lines of the whole view causing the checkBox to toggle on/off. The only way I see this working is in the `getView()` function using the stock `convertView` with a `setOnClickListener` and then manually finding which view and changing the checkBox. Is there a better way? It seems very inefficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did that the same way you described. In the XML document that you inflate inside your adapter's `getView()` method, add this attribute:

```
android:onClick="myMethod";
```

Then inside your activity, declare the myMethod, like this:

```
public void myMethod(View v) {
    CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.targetId);
    cb.setChecked(!cb.isChecked);
}
```

Comment: that's pretty nifty. I'm using fragments, and I want the checkbox to be checked on the row's click in the listView not just the checkBox toggle. Would this method still work for that situation?

Comment: Yeah, if you set the `onClick` attribute to the layout which populates the AdapterView then it will fire off regardless of what you click as long as the object you click is attached (is child) to the layout that uses `myMethod(View v)` as its onClick method.

Answer (score 1):

What you could also do is define a custom view:

checkable_row_view.xml:

```
<LinearLayout>
    <Checkbox
       android:id="@+id/checkbox/>
    <TextView
       android:id="@+id/textview/>
</LinearLayout>


public class CustomListviewItem extends LinearLayout implements Checkable{
    private TextView text;
    private Checkbox checkbox;
    private MyObject myObject; //the model class of the items you're displaying

    public CustomListviewItem(Context context){
        super(context);
    }

    public CustomListviewItem(Context context, AttributeSet attrs){
        super(context, attrs);
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        inflater.inflate(R.layout.checkable_row_view, this);
        text = findViewById(...);
        checkbox = findViewById(...);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChecked(){
        return myObject.isChecked();
    }

    @Override
    public void setChecked(boolean checked){
        myObject.setChecked(checked);
        checkbox.setChecked(checked);
    }

    @Override
    public void toggle(){
        myObject.setChecked(!myObject.isChecked());
        checkbox.setChecked(!checkbox.isChecked());
    }

    public void setText(String text){
        this.text.setText(text);
    }


    public void setMyObject...
}
```

custom_item_view.xml:

```
 <my.awesome.CustomListviewItem
       width and height stuff here... />
```

in your adapter:

```
static class ViewHolder{
    public CustomListviewItem customListviewItem;
}

@Override
public View getView(position, convertView, parent){
   //do viewholder stuff

 holder.customListviewItem.setText(theText);
 holder.customListviewItem.setChecked(shouldBeChecked)
}
```

Make sure to set the choice mode of your listview to CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE and use R.layout.custom_item_view as your item layout in your adapter.